# Median is higher than mean in a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

Why does my boxplot look like this? How on earth the median is 10 when the mean is 8? The variable is numeric and discrete, with range of 1-10

[image]

This is the code I used  `boxplot(implvdm ~ gndr, data = mydata, main = "Boxplot of implvdm by Gender", xlab = "Gender", ylab = "implvdm")`

And here's a sample of my data

```
structure(list(gndr = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), impdema = c(3L, 1L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), implvdm = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 
8L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 
9L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
8L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 0L, 
9L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Consider the data set 10, 10, 4. The median (under the usual definition) is 10, the mean is 8. What’s the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, I can't quite replicate your plot: when I run your code, only the `gndr==1` category has median 10.  Second, take a look at the distribution of the data:

```r
plot(table(subset(mydata, gndr == 1)$implvdm))
```

[image]

When the distribution is skewed in this way (**left skewed**), the median is larger than the mean.

Here you can see that more than half of the 49 values for `gndr==1` are equal to 10, so the median is 10.